# search min, max and average price Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controller

```
def show
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @product }
      end
 end
```

View

```
<% @product.compoFathers.each do |compo| %>
    <% compo.productSon.suppliers.each do |sonSuppl| %>
        <%= sonSuppl.price %> 
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I look for minimum, average and maximum price.

Please Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [dedicated database queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#average):

```
Product.average("price")
Product.maximum("price")
Product.minimum("price")
```

Reasons are:

- they are optimised
- you'll probably need pagination sooner or later so you should not need to load all data to get these information

Comment: Combining them into a single query would be rather faster, no?

Comment: those queries are blazing fast and I doubt you can merge them in a single one. If so I'm curious how

Comment: agreed, that's why my first point (optimisation) was not quite enough and this is where pagination issues enter the game.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet of code :-

```
<% average = minimum = maximum = total_price = count = 0  %>    
<% @product.compoFathers.each do |compo| %>
    <% compo.productSon.suppliers.each do |sonSuppl| %>
        <%= sonSuppl.price %> 
        <%  count +=1
            total_price += sonSuppl.price
            minimum = sonSuppl.price if minumum == 0
            maximum = sonSuppl.price if minumum == 0                
            if ( sonSuppl.price > minimum )
                if ( sonSuppl.price > maximum )
                    maximum = sonSuppl.price
                end
            else
                minimum = sonSuppl.price       # Previously it is minumum - 
            end
        %>            
    <% end %>
<% end %>    
Average = <%=average = total_price / count %>
Maximum = <%=maximum %>
Minimum = <%=minumum %>
```

Comment: are you really doing this in a view?

Comment: Updation made in that spell, plz cross check it. Let me know if you have error while executing the code.